# Chevy S10 pickup power steering

Tags: chevrolet, power-steering, s10

Is Mercon V ATF compatible for use in a Chevrolet S10 power steering pump reservoir?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If anything, I'd think you'd want to use Dexron VI, which is a GM product ... Mercon is a Ford product and I'm sure completely different. You don't mention which year of S10 you have, so no way to tell you what to use.

Comment: No but Dexron is.